# how to insert anchor tag in export csv report php?

Tags: php, csv

I want to insert anchor tag ( url open by csv report ) in csv export.

i have two variables for header and data respectively $CSV_header and $CSV_lines.

in $CSV_lines i have urls and i want to export it.

MY CSV CODE

```
$CSV_header =
"\"DEVELOPER NAME\",\"Url\" \n";

$CSV_lines =eregi_replace(" ", " ", "\"$developer_name\",\"$url\" \n");
```

for example $url = `<a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>`

```
$FILE_TIME = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$CSVfilename = "REPORT_$US$FILE_TIME.csv";
        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$CSVfilename\"");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        echo $CSV_header;
        echo $CSV_lines ;
```

Comment: I am using this code and it's work perfectly but in CSV full url shown but i want to show url title HYPERLINK(\"http://google.com\");

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points to consider..

1. `CSV` is plain text, and it doesn't support this type of format.
2. You shouldn't try to write your own `CSV`. Use `fputcsv()` if your'e  still going to continue working with a `CSV` format.
3. You can use an `XLS Builder` or some equivalent for whichever software you're looking to open it in.
4. You can use `.xls` extension and output a normal HTML Table and the spreadsheet software shall handle it gracefully.

---

```
<?php
$CSV_lines 
    = "<table border=1>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>DEVELOPER NAME</td>
          <td><a href='http://www.example.com'>Example</a></td>
        </tr>
      </table>";
$FILE_TIME = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$CSVfilename = "REPORT_$US$FILE_TIME.xls";
        header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$CSVfilename\"");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        echo $CSV_lines ;
?>
```

**[PHPFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/6gwc-0vyz)**